# Pushing a react client into a repo

Tags: git, github, repository, create-react-app

The deal is: I've got a nodejs server in the root folder. There is also a git repo in the same place. Also I have a create-react-app in the folder of "client".
The structure looks like this:

```
   /client
   server.js
   package.json
```

The problem is, when I push it to my github repo, the "client" folder content isn't getting added, I mean it stays empty having zero content inside, whereas there's supposed to be a react app in it.
Can anybody help me to figure out, what's going on?

Comment: Did you ever `git add` the files inside `client/`? Is there any `.gitignore` in play? Have you checked your `git status`?

Comment: I tried `git add client/*` the response is `fatal: Pathspec 'client/*' is in submodule 'client'`

Comment: So you have a git repo for the client, too. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, not actually. There initially was one (initialized by create-react-app), and I removed it. But the content in the "client" folder just doesn't get added to my repo. `git add .` doesn't work as well. And I only have 'node modules' in my .gitignore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Pathspec+is+in+submodule

Comment: Since I've ended up with same issue and same questions on stackoverflow couple of times I will give the solution in here: You need to remove all .git files recursively from top of your root folder by running this command "rm -rf .git". After that you need to re-initialize git as stated on github and all other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Do the below steps, provided that you do not have entry of `client` folder in your `.gitignore` file.

```
1. git add .   // it is dot(.) actually
2. git commit -m "you commit message"
3. git pull origin your_branch_name  //If multiple people pushing to repo otherwise you can skip this step
4. git push origin your_branch_name
```

Comment: This is the first thing I tried, and it doesn't help, the folder is still completely empty.

Comment: Try `git status` after you push your code. and still you see some files then something might be blocking your files from adding like `.gitignore` file.